# equidistant row of images not aligning html / css

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I have a site where 3 pages have a row of images that can be viewed larger upon rollover. On 2 pages the alignment works fine, these have 6 images in the row. The third page which is not working properly has 5 images per row.

The pages with 6 images are aligning perfectly - the left-most image is on its own, floating left, the other 5 are in their own divs within a div (movers-row) and are spaced 20% apart. The code for this working page is here: http://jsfiddle.net/AvNJY/

So using the same logic I tried to get the row with only 5 images to align, again doing the same as above and setting the distance to 25%. This made the last image in the row jump below the others. I played around with the percentage and for some reason at 24.4% it looks as if it's aligning correctly in all browsers apart from Firefox, when viewed at 100%. However as soon as you enlarge the site in any browser, the last image jumps again below the others (in Firefox this happens automatically). I am wondering what I am doing wrong on this page as I've tried everything I can think of - and can't understand why the 25% isn't doing it. The code for this page is here: http://jsfiddle.net/9K74d/

I would really appreciate some help if anyone knows the answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In case this helps, the technique that I have used for the equidistant objects is from this tutorial: http://css-tricks.com/equidistant-objects-with-css/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example in jsfiddle, is not clear but try the following:

add `overflow:auto` for `#studiomovers-row` and remove the `margin` of this id.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a rounding error - browsers can be surprisingly poor at math and make unexpected rounding errors.  Knock your % down to 24 or even 23 and see if that works.  You can always try putting the images into a single div container, sized to the correct, expected size, and set `overflow: hidden` in case there is a pixel or two that runs over.  That gives you a little margin of error and it's much better than having the layout break.

Comment: By the way, both layouts in your 2 jsfiddles work fine in my Chrome browser, but break in FireFox and IE.

Comment: Great thanks for letting me know. Managed to get it working using overflow:auto and setting the distance to 25%.